# How to Model and Load Type 2 Dimension Table in Snowflake Cloud Database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would like to know how can I create and load Type 2 (Slowly Changing) dimension table in snowflake cloud database. Most of the cases, the loading of this table involves updates and inserts of records up to 1-50 per day.
If we follow the traditional approach then will the snowflake storage will grow significantly in shot time as every small change it will create a separate storage per load.

Answer (score 1):

On inserts and updates, Snowflake creates new micropartitions, but based on what your time-travel settings for the table, then the stale micropartitions will be dropped.  So, I wouldn't worry too much about it (space is cheap, too).  If you are concerned with the time-travel or fail-safe creating an extra cost, you can use a Transient table, instead of permanent tables.  These will not have fail-safe costs.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-time-travel.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#comparison-of-table-types

Hope that helps.  Otherwise, there isn't any difference on how you should handle Type 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You could bring your data into a permanent table with `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE` statements.  This table would represent the "current state" of your dimension.  On this table you could create a `STREAM` object which tracks the changes, then setup a stored procedure to gather the data from the stream and write those changes to an SCD2 table.  The procedure can be invoked by a task running on a schedule or invoked from another task that successfully updates the "current state" table.  Finally, the SCD2 table could be transient to avoid added costs of fail-safe and added time-travel (as Mike mentioned in his answer).

***Flow:***
Data into "current state" table --> Task running proc reads from stream --> Updates SCD2

***Documentation:***
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html

Storage is cheap, but it is good to be cost aware.